Equality relates to directional derivative in Differential geometry
I'm currently at 3rd chapter of Lee's Intro. to Smooth Manifold and I spent quite a few hours on verifying the following equality on page 52

If $v_a\in \mathbb{R}^n_a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $v_a=v^ie_i\big|_a$ in terms of the standard basis, then by the chain rule $$D_{v|_a}f=v^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x ^i}(a)$$

Where the RHS is Einstein notation and $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$
, I have the following justification but my calculus is super bad and I am not sure if this is correct.
I know that by definition given in Lee
$$D_v\big|_af= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(a+tv)$$
Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be as $t\mapsto (a+tv)$ Then I have
$$D_v\big|_af= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(f\circ g)(t)$$
So, this is the deriative of a function $(f\circ g):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ so I apply chain rule and get
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(f\big(g(t)\big) \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g(t)$$
Where
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g(t)= \big(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g^1(t),\ldots, \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g^n(t)\big)$$
for each $i\in [n]$ I have
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g^i(t)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g^i(t+h)-g^i(t)}{h}=v^i$$
So, $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}g(t)=\big(v^1,\ldots,v^n\big)$
Whereas, $$ \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f\big(g(t)\big)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f\big(a+tv\big)= \sum^n_{i=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a+tv) $$
evaluated at $t=0$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f\big(g(t)\big)= \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a)$$
But clearly this is completely off. One is a vector the other is a scalar and they dont multiply to the RHS of the equality.
Or I tried to just apply the chain rule for partial derivative given from the appendix,
where I can have the following
$$\sum_{i}\frac{\partial f^k}{\partial x^i}\big(g(t))\frac{\partial g^i}{\partial (y^j)}(t)$$
I geuess $f^k=f$ because $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} $ and $y^j=t$ for all $j$ because $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ so I have
$$\sum_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\big(g(t))\frac{d g^i}{dt}(t)=\sum_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a+tv)v^i$$
evaluated at $t=0$ give us the desired RHS?
Applying the partial derivative gives me what I want I dont quite get why my first justification doesnt work. It would be nice if someone could help me find my mistakes. Thanks!

You need to revise carefully. The derivative of $f(g(t))$ is totally different from the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $g(t)$.
